# Sitecore: Save date in sitecore field with type="DateTime" from <Input type="text">

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

If I have an html control in my page.

```
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

On a button click, I save the value of input `dateFrom` to a Sitecore item's field with type "`DateTime`"

**CodeBehind:**

```
item["Visible From"] = dateFrom.Value;
```

I am using Jquery to show a calendar when user clicks inside the input `dateFrom`

```
$(function () {
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker();
    });
```

After saving the item, the result I see in the "Content Editor" is:
[image]

The correct date is some how not saving. I also tried with `<asp:TextBox` 
instead of `<input type="text"` but still same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The date is stored in ISO 8601 format in the backend, use the Sitecore helper methods to get it into the correct format:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateFrom.Value);
var isoDate = DateUtil.ToIsoDate(dateTime);
item["Visible From"] = isoDate ;
```

You can find more info in this article about [Using DateTime And Date Fields In Sitecore](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/using-date-and-datetime-fields-in-sitecore)

Answer (score 0):

The dates are stored in Sitecore in its own (string-based) format. You may check that if you check **View --> Raw Vales** from a menu above.

Sitecore has its own helper class called DateUtil to work with dates and times.

```
string storedDateTimeValue = DateUtil.DateTimeToIsoDate(DateTime.Now);
```

or reverse operation:

```
DateTime dt = DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(storedDateTimeValue);
```

[Here is](https://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.0/Sitecore.DateUtilMembers.html) a bit outdated, but correct information on that DateUtil class API.